React Native Reanimated Rotate an Animated.View on a negative y-axis value
I haven't been able to find any instructions on how to do this.
So, currently, I can "flip" an Animated.View using Gesture Handler. It works just like I want except that I want the bottom of the view to be stationary. Right now it will RotateX on the y-axis equal to 0, which causes the view to flip forward and/or backward in the direct center of the Animated.View.
However, I want the view to flip on a negative y-axis, so that the bottom of the view doesn't move at all, but the top still moves.
Think of it like this. Currently my view is flipping like a coin (both the top and bottom move), but what I want instead is for the view to fall forward (only the top to move) so that it looks more like a book falling forward on its face.
My current code is very simple:
 const rotation = useSharedValue(0)

 const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(()=>{
  return{
    
  transform: [
    { rotateX: `${rotation.value}deg`}
  ]

}
 })


I'm wondering if any experts on reanimated can let me know what to add to this code to get that view to fall forward rather than flip like a coin? Or if you could direct me to a tutorial that explains it, that would be great. Thanks

To rotate an Animated.View in React Native Reanimated based on a
negative Y-axis value, you can use the rotateY transformation. In
Reanimated 2, you can create an animation driven by an animated value
that maps the input (e.g., Y-axis) to a rotation transformation.
useSharedValue: yAxis is a shared value initialized to 0.
withTiming: Smoothly animates the yAxis value to -45 (negative rotation) over 1 second.
useAnimatedStyle: Maps the yAxis value to the rotateY transformation degrees.
rotateY: The rotateY property applies a 3D rotation around the Y-axis, and negative values rotate in the opposite direction
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Animated, { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, withTiming } from 
"react-native-reanimated";
export default function App() {
const yAxis = useSharedValue(0);                                    // 
Shared value for the Y-axis
React.useEffect(() => {
    yAxis.value = withTiming(-45, { duration: 1000 });              // 
Rotate to -45 degrees
}, []);
const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
        transform: [{rotateY: `${yAxis.value}deg`}],
    }
});
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]} />
    </View>
);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: { flex: 1,
justifyContent: "center",
alignItems: "center", 
backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5" 
},
box: {
width: 100,
height: 100,
backgroundColor: "purple"
}
});


Thanks Tina! I've been away from my workshop for a week or so. I'll run your code theory and let you know how it goes. Big thanks for the response in the meantime.
